ModelSim has inconsistent output. Is this a bug?
I noticed that suddenly a signal in my testbench turned x.
I tried to find the cause and according to the verilog, the signal should ever be only either z or 0.
Since sda_padoen_o is 0, sda should be sda_pad_o which should always be 0.
Somehow sda is x nonetheless.
Is there a flaw in my conclusion or did I find a bug in modelsim?

…
inout wire sda
…
assign sda = sda_padoen_o ? 1'bz : sda_pad_o;
…
i2c_master_byte_ctrl byte_controller (… .sda_o(sda_pad_o), …);

…
output wire sda_o;
…
i2c_master_bit_ctrl bit_controller (… .sda_o(sda_o), …);

…
output wire sda_o;
…
assign sda_o = 1'b0;


When sda_padoen_o is 1, sda is also 1 so there is clearly another driver somewhere. When there are to conflicting drivers the result is x.
